# Geolocation fill address form automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, geolocation

I have this form, and i want to fill the address, city, state and zip code input fields automatically with the geolocation of the users, i'm a noob in the javascript area and i really need help with this.

This is the code i have and i need help in creating the javascript that will fill the fields.

```
<form name="catcustomcontentform11679" onsubmit="return checkWholeForm11679(this)" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="/CustomContentProcess.aspx?CCID=24718&amp;OID={module_oid}&amp;OTYPE={module_otype}">
    <table class="webforms" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" border="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="ItemName">Item Name</label><br />
                <input class="cat_textbox_small" type="text" name="ItemName" id="ItemName" maxlength="255" /> &bull;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="ItemDescription">Item Description</label><br />
                <textarea name="ItemDescription" id="ItemDescription" cols="10" rows="4" class="cat_listbox"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="ItemAddress">Address</label><br />
                <input type="text" name="ItemAddress" id="ItemAddress" class="cat_textbox" maxlength="500" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="ItemCity">City</label><br />
                <input type="text" name="ItemCity" id="ItemCity" class="cat_textbox" maxlength="255" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="ItemState">State</label><br />
                <input type="text" name="ItemState" id="ItemState" class="cat_textbox" maxlength="255" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="ItemZip">Zipcode/Postcode</label><br />
                <input type="text" name="ItemZip" id="ItemZip" class="cat_textbox" maxlength="255" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="ItemCountry">Country</label><br />
                <select name="ItemCountry" id="ItemCountry" class="cat_dropdown">
                <option value=" ">-- Select Country --</option>
                <option value="MX" selected="selected">MEXICO</option>
                </select></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="CAT_Custom_1">Last Name</label><br />
                <input type="text" maxlength="4000" name="CAT_Custom_1" id="CAT_Custom_1" class="cat_textbox" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="CAT_Custom_2">Email Address</label><br />
                <input type="text" maxlength="4000" name="CAT_Custom_2" id="CAT_Custom_2" class="cat_textbox" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input class="cat_button" type="submit" value="Submit" id="catcustomcontentbutton" /></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

---

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/CatalystScripts/ValidationFunctions.js?vs=b1566.r451189-phase1"></script>
```

---

```
//<![CDATA[
var submitcount11679 = 0;
function checkWholeForm11679(theForm){
var why = "";
if (theForm.ItemName) why += isEmpty(theForm.ItemName.value, "Item Name");
if (why != ""){alert(why);return false;}
if(submitcount11679 == 0){
submitcount11679++;theForm.submit();return false;
}else{
alert("Form submission is in progress.");return false;
}
}
//]]>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing something like this: (You may want to give the user an option to enter there address in. For cases like, there not at home when ordering, there at friends house, at work, etc. You may not want to take the actual latitude and longitude to fill in there address but to help narrow it down like this example shows.

http://jsfiddle.net/bobrierton/vbc1a5uo/

```js
var placeSearch, autocomplete;
var componentForm = {
  route: 'long_name',
  locality: 'long_name',
  administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
  postal_code: 'short_name'
};

function initialize() {
  // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search
  // to geographical location types.
  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */
    (document.getElementById('autocomplete')), {
      types: ['geocode']
    });
  // When the user selects an address from the dropdown,
  // populate the address fields in the form.
  google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
    fillInAddress();
  });
}

// [START region_fillform]
function fillInAddress() {
  // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

  for (var component in componentForm) {
    document.getElementById(component).value = '';
    document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
  }

  // Get each component of the address from the place details
  // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
  for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
    var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
    if (componentForm[addressType]) {
      var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
      document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
   
    }
  }
  //var keys=[];for (var key in place.address_components[0]) keys.push(key);
  //alert(keys):
  document.getElementById('autocomplete').value = 
    place.address_components[0]['long_name'] + ' ' +
    place.address_components[1]['long_name'];
  
  /*document.getElementById('route').value = (document.getElementById('chbSame').checked ? document.getElementById('autocomplete').value : '');*/
  document.getElementById('route').value = '';
}
  // [END region_fillform]

// [START region_geolocation]
// Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
// as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
function geolocate() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var geolocation = new google.maps.LatLng(
        position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
      var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
        center: geolocation,
        radius: position.coords.accuracy
      });
      autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
    });
  }
}

  // [END region_geolocation]
initialize();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=places"></script>
<tbody>
         <tr>
                <td><label for="ItemAddress">Address</label>
                <input type="text" name="ItemAddress" id="autocomplete" class="cat_textbox" maxlength="500" onFocus="geolocate()" /><br></td>
            </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><label for="ItemAddress2">Address2</label>
                <input type="text" name="ItemAddress2" id="route" class="cat_textbox" maxlength="500" /><br></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="ItemCity">City</label>
                <input type="text" name="ItemCity" id="locality" class="cat_textbox" maxlength="255" /><br></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="ItemState">State</label>
                <input type="text" name="ItemState" id="administrative_area_level_1" class="cat_textbox" maxlength="255" /><br></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="ItemZip">Zipcode/Postcode</label>
                <input type="text" name="ItemZip" id="postal_code" class="cat_textbox" maxlength="255" /></td>
            </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: This works great!, but unfortunately i don't want the customers to input the address, i need it to be automatically filled.

Comment: yes, its a form to report problems that you might find in your way, something like if you see that a light in your street not working or something like that, i actually want something like this [link](http://cre84.me/formmapper/geolocate.html) just the part that fills the form

Answer (score 0):

You might find that populating the address line for a user based on their lat/long supplied by their device a little hit or miss.

On a device with a GPS unit the location should be quite accurate, however it's likely that it will miss on the building number sometimes. Devices without GPS sometimes give an approximate location which can sometimes be quite far off.

This could cause some friction for your users, having to edit or delete the text you have pre-populated.

Also consider that when some is using their mobile device they are likely to be away from home, so it would populate the fields with information from their current location rather than the address they want to use.

If you want to speed up the entry of an address, using a zipcode to address lookup service might be a better option.